# train_on_batch error after first a successful first batch

Tags: keras

I have the following code. This is within the class CNNEnv.

```
    def step(self, a_t, i):
        self.a_t = a_t
        self.i = i

        # Batch size of 32
        # 1875 * 32 = 60000 -> # of training samples
        self.X_train = self.X_train[self.i * 32:(self.i + 1) * 32]
        self.y_train = self.y_train[self.i * 32:(self.i + 1) * 32]

        # Train & evaluate one iteration
        self.model.train_on_batch(self.X_train, self.y_train)
        self.scores = self.model.test_on_batch(self.X_test, self.y_test)
        self.scores = self.scores[1] * 100

        return self.X_train.shape, self.y_train.shape, self.scores
```

The following is an external script that calls this. It works for the first iteration. However, on the second iteration, there's an error.

```
from CNN import CNNEnv

# Instantiate class and assign to object env
env = CNNEnv()

# Call function within class
a, b, c = env.step(0.001, 1)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)


# Call function within class second time
d, e, f = env.step(0.001, 2)

print(d)
print(e)
print(f)
```

Error after first batch

```
First batch:
(32, 1, 28, 28)
(32, 10)
9.42000001669
Error on second batch:
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:422] could not set cudnn tensor descriptor: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
```

The weird thing is that if I were to do the following, it works when I call the `train_on_batch` twice without using a class. But I need the class because my external script has to call the function this way. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. User error. Variable assignment issue.

Should use self.X_batch instead of self.X_train. This would solve the problem if anyone is facing it.